# PHP - Changing a value from a query result using foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have a result from a SQL query stored inside $assignmentsViewList:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
    (
        [assign_id] => 302
        [ClassCount] => 25
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [assign_id] => 303
        [ClassCount] => 25
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [assign_id] => 325
        [ClassCount] => 25
    )

)
```

When I use it inside a foreach to change the value of ClassCount:

```
foreach ($assignmentsViewList as $task) {
    $task['ClassCount'] = 2;
}
```

It doesn't work. But if I try this:

```
$assignmentsViewList[0]['ClassCount']=2;
```

The code works well. But I need it to work inside the foreach loop.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Do you want to update all the `ClassCount` values? Or just one?

Comment: I am changing all the ClassCount values.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. It should solve your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $task with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Reference: [PHP foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Try this:

```
foreach ($assignmentsViewList as &$task) {
    $task['ClassCount'] = 2;   /* It will overwrite all 'ClassCount' values to 2 */
}
```

Comment: I have seen this '&' before, but I didn't know that this is needed when modifying. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`use &` .

Its means iterated over references to actual values of array  `&$task`

```
 foreach ($assignmentsViewList as &$task)
{
  $task['ClassCount'] = 2;  values of array
}
```

without & means its iterated over copy of array value.so its not overwrite your array.

[take a look in documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)